# Combine two references into one or some serious regex work

Tags: regex

### Question, basically

1. If I have a regex `((key1)(value1)|(key2)(value2))`, `key1` is ref'd by `$2` & `key2` by `$4`. Is it possible to combine these into the same reference? (I'm guessing no)

   - Thus `$7` might be key & `$8` might be value, regardless of which capture group it originated in
2. Any regex masters who can solve the below? I've spent a couple hours on it and am kinda stuck.

I would like it to work across different regex engines with minimal modifications. Been testing with PCRE on regexr.com

### What I'm doing

I'm trying to make a file format that is parsed into key/value pairs with a single regex.

There's just a few rules:

1. Keys are a string of characters at the start of a line, followed by a colon (`:`).

   - So far, I'm just using `[a-z]+` for the keys, but that will be expanded to some more characters. I don't think that will functionally change the regex.
2. values can be multi-line
3. all white-space is trimmed from values

   - I don't think I've added this to the regex yet
4. Values end when another key begins
5. delimiters can be used to wrap values in the format `key:DELIM:` then the value, then `:DELIM:` on it's own line.
6. Delimiter can be an empty string, thus `::` serves as a delimiter

### The regex I have

- Correctly matches non-delimited keys & values

  - `([a-z]+):((?:(?:.|\n|\r)(?!^[a-z]+:))+)`
- Correctly matches delimited keys & values

  - `([a-z]+):([A-Z]*:)((.|\r|\n)*)^:\2`
- Matches everything correctly, BUT requires two sets of references

  - `(?:(?:([a-z]+):([A-Z]*:)((.|\r|\n)*)^:\2)|([a-z]+):((?:(?:.|\n|\r)(?!^[a-z]+:))+))`
  - `$1` & `$5` are keys. `$3` & `$6` are values

### Sample Input

```
key: value 1
nightmare:DELIM:
notakey:
    obviously not a key
notakey:
:DELIM:
abc: value 2
new line
anotherkey:: value 
nostring: on this one
::
```

Which would yield These key/value pairs

#### key

```
value1
```

#### nightmare

```
notakey:
    obviously not a key
notakey:
```

#### abc

```
value 2
new line
```

#### anotherkey

```
value 
nostring: on this one
```

### My latest attempt

My latest attempt got me here, but it doesn't actually match anything:

```regex
^([a-z]+): # key CP#1
    ((?:[A-Z]*:)? # delimiter, optional
        (?:\s*(\r?\n|$)) # whitespace, new line OR end of file (line?)
    ) # CP#2
    (    # value, CP#3
        (?:(?:
            (?:.|\n|\r) # characters we want
            (?!^[a-z]+:) # But NOT if those characters make up a key
        )+)          
    | # or
        
        ((.|\r|\n)*) # characters we want
        ^:\2 # Ends with delimiter

    )           # delimited value
```

Comment: `((key1)(value1)|(key2)(value2))` => `(?|(key1)(value1)|(key2)(value2))`. And never use `(.|\r|\n)*`, use `(?s).*`

Comment: Holy crumb. I'm gonna give that a go!

Comment: Yeah, that's great. I still have some work to do to make it all work, but I think that'll get me there. & thanks for the note about `(?s).*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Neither `(?s)` nor `(?|` appear to work in javascript. Any alternative ideas?

Comment: Sure: 1) to match any char, use `[^]` or `[\s\S]`, 2) branch reset group is not supported so use your current approach with a non-capturing group and manipulate the group values upon getting a match.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the commenter for the `?|` operator, which turns out to be what I needed.

`((key1)(value1)|(key2)(value2))` => `(?|(key1)(value1)|(key2)(value2)).`

`(?|(?:([a-z]+):([A-Z]*:)((.|\r|\n)*)^:\2)|([a-z]+):()((?:(?:.|\n|\r)(?!^[a-z]+:))+))` basically does it, though the final product certainly still needs more work.

Comment: Are you aware that `(?:.|\n|\r)` without quantifier doesn't match Windows EOL? as said in comment where you've taken this regex, use `(?s).`

Comment: I wasn't. I didn't know why that was bad, but I did plan to update my regex with `(?s).*` anyway!